# Casting malloc to (void**)

Tags: c++, malloc

Let's say, in C++ I use `malloc` to allocate memory for 4x void pointers:

```
malloc(4*sizeof(void*))
```

Since `malloc` returns a void pointer I assume that the following assignment is valid:

```
void *x;
x=(void*)malloc(4*sizeof(void*));
```

However, most of the code that I find on the forums casts to `(void**)` before assignment, like so:

```
void **y;
y=(void**)malloc((4*sizeof(void*));
```

I understand that this is a "pointer to pointer" casting but what purpose does this serve?
What advantage does `(void**)` casting have over `(void*)`? Is it because I'm allocating memory to pointers rather than values?

Another question... would `(void**)` casting in the case above be equivalent to the following?

```
int *x;
x=(void*)malloc(4*sizeof(void*));
int **y;
y=&x;
```

Comment: C++ requires you to explicitly convert pointers. It forces you to stop and think, "Am I doing the right thing?" When you see a cast like that (or a `reinterpret_cast`) for any reason in C++ you should stop and wonder if a mistake is being made and then covered up by a bigger mistake. And after wondering you should make sure there isn't a mistake.  Side note: In C++ you only want to use `malloc` in rare circumstances when working on very finicky, low-level building blocks. Prefer a library container, then `new`, and finally `malloc` or friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you are allocating memory for an integer variable then we use pointer to an integer `int*`

suppose if you want to allocate memory for pointer variable , then we use pointer to poniter `int**`

same goes for `void*` as well , hope below example helps you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int iVar = 99;
    int *piVar;
    int **ppiVar;
    void *vptr;
    void **vpptr; // here void * also, enough, but we should know when we extract, what to extract 

    piVar = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *piVar = 10;

    ppiVar = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    *ppiVar = piVar;

    vptr = &iVar;
    vpptr = &vptr;

    printf("piVar = %d , ppiVar = %d vptr = %d and vpptr =%d \n", *piVar,**ppiVar, *(int* )vptr, **(int **)vpptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is `C` code, not C++.  A call to `malloc` requires a cast in C++.